# Directly changing an argument to a subroutine

Tags: perl

It would make a lot of things easier in my script if I could use subroutines in the way that shift, push, and other built-in subroutines work: they can all directly change the variable that is passed to it without the need to return the change.

When I try to do this the variable is copied at some point and I appear to be simply changing the copy. I understand that this would be fine with references but it even happens with arrays and hashes, where I feel like I am simply passing the variable I was working on to the sub so that more work can be done on it:

```
@it = (10,11);
changeThis(@it);
print join(" ", @it),"\n"; #prints 10 11 but not 12

sub changeThis{
    $_[2] = 12;
}
```

Is there a way to do this? I understand that it isn't best practice, but in my case it would be very convenient.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that the sub call expands the variable to a list of values, which are passed on to the sub routine. I.e. a copy is passed, not the variable itself. Your sub call is equal to:

```
changeThis(11, 12);
```

If you wish to change the original array, pass a reference instead:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @it = (10,11);
changeThis(\@it);
print join(" ", @it),"\n";

sub changeThis{
    my $array = shift;
    $$array[2] = 12;
}
```

Also, `@_[2]` will give you the warning:

```
Scalar value @_[2] better written as $_[2]
```

If you `use warnings`, which of course you should. There is no good reason to not turn on warnings and strict, unless you know exactly what you are doing.

Comment: Oh I see the problem now! However, in that case it feels a bit contradictory that the built-in functions require dereferenced variables.

Comment: @kikumbob Which built-in functions are you referring to?

Comment: shift, unshift, push, pop etc. Also, of course I use warnings! The code I gave was a snippet that I didn't bother a compiler with (I will next time...) :)

Comment: @kikumbob That's a good point. It looks a bit inconsistent. I don't know why it is like that, but perhaps someone else does.

Comment: @kikumbob Look at mirod's answer for an explanation of how you can emulate the built-in functions.

Answer (score 10):

That's what prototypes are for:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

sub changeThis(\@);     # the argument will be seen as an array ref (prototype must come before the call!)

my @it = (10,11);  
changeThis @it;         # even when called with an array
print join(" ", @it),"\n"; #prints 10 11 12

sub changeThis(\@)
  { my( $ar)= @_; $ar->[2]= 12; }
```

See http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsub.html#Prototypes for more information.

It's not really a popular method though, passing actual array references is probably a better alternative, with less magic involved.

Comment: +1 for answering (the how-part of) OP's question in the comments to my answer. And for teaching me something new as well. :)

Comment: the fact that the original arguments are aliased is useful, prototypes OTOH... they were created exactly for the purpose of emulating the syntax of Perl's built-ins, but few people actually use them. https://www.socialtext.net/perl5/prototype has also some more info and links

Comment: Yes, this answers the other half of my question. Its a shame I only have enough ink for one tick :-(

Comment: well, passing by reference is a better way anyway, so better leave the proper technique at the top of the answer list.

Answer (score 2):

As the previous answers suggest, you should use a reference passed to the subroutine.
Additionally you also can use implicit referencing if you want to read trough the [documentation for Prototypes](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsub.html#Prototypes)

```
sub changeThis(\@);

@it = (10,11);
changeThis @it;
print join(" ", @it),"\n"; #prints 10 11 12

sub changeThis(\@){
    $_[0][2] = 12;
}
```

(note that you either have to predeclare your subs before the first call or put the sub definitions on top.)